# Multi-lingual web application - how do I detect the user's language in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, multilingual, language-switching

I'm building an ASP.NET web application, and all of my strings are stored in a resource file. I'd like to add a second language to my application, and ideally, I'd like to auto-detect the user's browser language (or windows language) and default to that, instead of making them choose something besides English. Currently, I'm handling all the resource population manually, so adding a second resource file and language is trivial from my point of view, if I had an easy way to automatically figure out what language to display.

Has anybody done this, or do you have any thoughts about how I might retrieve that value? Since ASP.NET is server-based, I don't seem to have any access to specific browser settings.

**RESOLUTION**: Here's what I ended up doing. I used a "For Each" to go through "HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages" and search for one I support. I'm actually just checking the left two characters, since we don't support any dialects yet - just English and Spanish. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [article (linked to archive.org as original link is now dead)](http://web.archive.org/web/20080930115525/http://microsoft.apress.com/asptodayarchive/71804/website-internationalization-using-asp) might be helpful with auto detecting the browser's language setting.

[EDIT] Yes. The quoted article does not use ASP.NET. This [article](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/localization/culture.aspx#autoculture) does.

Comment: Though it's not .NET, I found the first article way more informative than the second, and it moved me in the right direction.

Answer (score 21):

Try this in the web.config:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
```

This will cause ASP.NET to auto-detect the client's culture from the request header. You can also set this on a per-page basis via the Page attribute.

Comment: maxam: I wrapped your code in a formatted code block to show the <>s. "edit" the response to see how this looks, if you're interested.

Comment: This worked for me (ps: I didn't need to use the 'enableClientBasedCulture' setting)

Comment: As indicated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.100).aspx), enableClientBasedCulture "is not in use at this time"

Comment: Thanks, Mart! Edited the post to remove the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question, as localization in [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) is overlooked by many developers.

ASP.NET ***should*** automatically pick up on the user's browser settings and force the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to the user's browser language. You can force the issue with a line in `Page_OnInit()` like:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0]);
```

How can you test this? Enter the languages panel on our browser and change settings.

Answer (score 2):

The client generally sets [Accept-Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests) in the HTTP request header with a quantitatively scored list of preferred language, conventionally (but not necessarily) in order of most favored to least favored. You can parse that, but as Maxam has noted, [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) does have a mechanism for doing that on your behalf.

Answer (score 2):

Request.UserLanguages in ASP.NET 4 parses this as a string array.

Good info: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a user's Locale based on the browser's Locale setting. If no setting
    /// is provided the default Locale is used.
    /// </summary>

public static void SetUserLocale(string CurrencySymbol, bool SetUiCulture)
{
    HttpRequest Request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    if (Request.UserLanguages == null)
        return;

    string Lang = Request.UserLanguages[0];
    if (Lang != null)
    {
        // *** Problems with Turkish Locale and upper/lower case
        // *** DataRow/DataTable indexes
        if (Lang.StartsWith("tr"))
            return;

        if (Lang.Length < 3)
            Lang = Lang + "-" + Lang.ToUpper();
        try
        {
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Lang);
            if (CurrencySymbol != null && CurrencySymbol != "")
                Culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = CurrencySymbol;

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Culture;

            if (SetUiCulture)
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Culture;
        }
        catch
        { ;}
    }
}
```

The source of this article is here:
[How to detect browser language](http://forums.asp.net/t/1052219.aspx/1)