# C# DataFormatString for thousands dot separator (Asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, format

In my model I want to format the output of a double. 
I'm trying to output a number like this:

*100000000*
as
*100.000.000*  (simply a dot separator)

But by using this (currency format)

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
```

Result => 424.232.344 kr

I also get the currency symbol (depending on the culture, in my case "kr") and I **don't** want that. I simply want the dot separator but without the currency.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `{0:#,#}` work? -- See also [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: check this for more options https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Corak, have tried. It results in spaces instead of dots.

Comment: @Ian Have checked it, does not contain my desired output.

Comment: @Ian - yes, that is probably, because the thousands-separator of your current(UI)culture has it defined like that. Sorry, I'm not versed enough in MVC to know how you can specify a different language. Usually, you can do something like `1000.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))`. But I think that's not possible with data annotations, because the culture isn't a compile constant.

Answer (score 5):

Because ["C" means *currency* in that format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString) and it uses [`CurrencySymbol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol) of your `CurrentCulture` setting.

You can use [The `"N"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString) instead.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}")]
```

Based on your comment, looks like your `CurrentCulture` using white space as `NumberGroupSeparator` but uses `.` as a `CurrencyGroupSeparator`.

In such a case, you can set it's `NumberGroupSeparator` to `.` and you will be fine.

Read: [Is there a way of setting culture for a whole application? All current threads and new threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/468791/447156)

Comment: Yes I am aware that C stands for currency. I Have tried your suggestion and it returns 424 232 344,00 (spaces instead of dots.)

Comment: @ChrisRun Updated my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I'm not able to set the NumberGroupSeparator in this case, since the instance is readonly.

Comment: @ChrisRun `NumberGroupSeparator` property is not read-only but your culture setting _might_ be. Have you ever check this question for this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/18728505/447156

Comment: My mistake, yes you are correct, the culture setting is readonly. Have not, will check it out, thanks.