# The value is not valid for Date in en-US culture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, datepicker, viewmodel

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 application which I am currently globalising.

In `de-DE` culture of the server my Date in the following format passes the serverside validation fine: `dd.MM.yyyy`

When I change the culture of the server to `en-US` the Display of the Date gets correctly converted to the `MM/dd/yyyy` date format. But when I click on send, server side validation fails.

[image: result of validation]

`ModelState.IsValid` is false and the date arrives in the controller as: `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`

This is my input field:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Date, Resource_Entries.DateFormat, new {@class = "form-control"})`

This `Resource_Entries.DateFormat` is a value that is saved in a .resx file. In the en-US resx file this is saved there: `{0:MM/dd/yyyy}`

I use the TextBoxFor Helper because I use a [bootstrap datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/).

In my Model I have the following:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Error), ErrorMessageResourceName = "EntryEditViewModel_Date_Required")]
public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

How can I fix this? I want the solution to work with de-DE culture aswell.

Comment: Which culture do you change to en-US? (Client, server, ...?)

Comment: @Richard Server

Comment: @Igor This actually solved my issue. I'm surprised! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Igor But how can I change the display format of this for different cultures? I haven't found a method to specify DisplayFormat in a resx file and link the DataFormatString in the model to it. That's why I used Resource_Entries.DateFormat on the TextBoxFor Helper. Or is that also possible with EditorFor? (referring to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6001664/5504438)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18728610/1260204

Comment: @Igor Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Igor I noticed that this didn't quite correctly solve the whole issue. If I enter a date like: 10/12/2016 it gets saved as: 12/10/2016. 
When I try to enter a date like: 10/13/2016, I get an error message. " The value '10/13/2016' is not valid for Date"
The culture of the Server is set to en-US. Tell me if you need more information!

Comment: @Igor I am still struggling with this. Would be glad for some help.

Comment: Did you add `<globalization culture="en-US"/>` to your web.config?

Comment: @Igor No because it is a multi language application.

Comment: @Igor I solved it now because I now use a different Date Format for the English Language (dd/MM/yyyy instead of MM/dd/yyyy)