# Changing locale for window-menu in wpf app

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a localized WPF application, which changes the system menu and creates a context-menu on the systray icon with win32 functions.

All this works quite fine unless the target language is chinese or japanese.
Then the menu items seem to consist of strings with question-marks, unless the startup locale for the application is also chinese/japanese.

Setting CultureInfo doesn't help here, and calling SetThreadLocale() and/or SetThreadPreferredUILanguages() doesn't seem to help either.

Any hints for me?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256229/multi-lingual-web-application-how-do-i-detect-the-users-language-in-asp-net

Comment: Thanks, but the applicable parts of this answer (setting CurrentCulture, CurrentUICulture, ...) unfortunately doesn't work.